# Why I'm getting an error "not all code paths return a value"?

Tags: c#

```
public InventoryQuotingRules AddANewPolicyButtonClick(IWebDriver driver)
{
    Reusable_Library.ClickByJs(driver, AddANewPolicyButton, "Click on Add a new policy button");
}
```

Comment: Because you promised to return a `InventoryQuotingRules` but actually return nothing

Comment: Errors from building C# code usually display with numbers prefixed with `CS` - in this case, the error to look up is [CS0161](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs0161).

Comment: If ClickByJs if a functio, perhaps you need to write `return Reusable_Library.ClickByJs(driver, AddANewPolicyButton, "Click on Add a new policy button");`. Otherwise `return /* something being type of InventoryQuotingRules */;`.

Answer (score 3):

In the function signature you declare that the function returns an `InventoryQuotingRules`, yet inside the function definition there is no `return` statement, so even though the function is supposed to return a `InventoryQuotingRules`, it doesn't return anything.

Comment: I appreciate! Thank you so much!